# Redis flushed unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I was using redis with node.js for 2 years, and it never had been flushed unexpectedly -- redis provided great persistence.

However I saw these logs and found out redis is flushed:

```
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:02.256 - DB 0: 1322 keys (538 volatile) in 2048 slots HT.
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:02.256 - 9 clients connected (0 slaves), 1574720 bytes in use
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:07.262 - DB 0: 1327 keys (543 volatile) in 2048 slots HT.
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:07.262 - 9 clients connected (0 slaves), 1575280 bytes in use
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:09.749 - Accepted 222.190.111.119:37280
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:09.791 * DB saved on disk
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:09.861 - Client closed connection
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:09.914 - Accepted 222.190.111.119:37288
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:09.966 - Client closed connection
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.019 - Accepted 222.190.111.119:37293
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.069 - Client closed connection
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.142 - Accepted 222.190.111.119:37299
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.212 - Client closed connection
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.267 - Accepted 222.190.111.119:37308
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.319 - Client closed connection
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.396 - Accepted 222.190.111.119:37323
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.449 * DB saved on disk
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.523 - Client closed connection
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.577 - Accepted 222.190.111.119:37347
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.629 - Client closed connection
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.703 - Accepted 222.190.111.119:37354
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.741 * DB saved on disk
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.814 - Client closed connection
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.870 - Accepted 222.190.111.119:37366
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:10.921 - Client closed connection
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:12.292 - DB 0: 2 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:12.292 - 9 clients connected (0 slaves), 990936 bytes in use
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:17.299 - DB 0: 2 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:17.299 - 9 clients connected (0 slaves), 990936 bytes in use
[1205] 08 Nov 06:05:22.305 - DB 0: 2 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
```

You can see that it contained 1327 keys at 06:05:07, and suddenly some client closed connection events fired and then it came to 2 keys at 06:05:12.

I am using node.js redis module to handle redis, and there is no code flushing redis entirely.

What could be the reason of this?